# Application monitoring software?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, monitoring

I'm running Fiery Command Workstation on a Mac and it tends to crash every couple of days.

I've been looking in the Console but it shows any events for FCW that are a few days old, not for the days I know it crashed.

Can anyone recommend software that can monitor specific apps so that when they hang or crash, it gets logged (and as a bonus, send out email notifications)?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: El Capitan, 10.11.6